# Before emitting observable, check if observer meets some criteria

Tags: android, rx-java2

Suppose I have an event bus:

```
public class MessageEventBus {
    private static MessageEventBus INSTANCE;
    private PublishSubject<Message> bus = PublishSubject.create();

    private MessageEventBus() {};

    public static MessageEventBus instance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new MessageEventBus();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void send(Message message) {
        bus.onNext(message);
    }

    public Observable<Message> toObservable() {
        return bus;
    }

    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return bus.hasObservers();
    }
}
```

Inside an Android service, events are pushed to the bus:

```
MessageEventBus bus = MessageEventBus.instance();
Message message = new Message(userId, text);
if (bus.hasObservers()) {
    bus.send(message);
    return;
}
```

And here's the point (in a MVP presenter) where I attach an observer to the event bus:

```
MessageEventBus bus = MessageEventBus.instance();
bus.toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(message -> {
            if (message.userId == userId) {
                view.messageReceived(message);        
            }
        });
```

How do I move the `if (message.userId == userId)` check from the presenter to the service? Or perhaps move that check to the event bus itself? Something like the following pseudocode in the service:

```
MessageEventBus bus = MessageEventBus.instance();
Message message = new Message(userId, text);
if (bus.hasObservers() && message.userId == theUserIdInThePresenter) {
    bus.send(message);
}
```

Or in other words, how do I check if an observer attached to an observable meets some criteria before actually emitting that observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Observer-Observable pattern, the Obsrvables should not care about the observers which subscribe to them.
Their purpose is to emit data.
However you can filter with more elegant way with [filter operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html). you have 2 possibilities:

1- put filter inside Presenter:

```
        MessageEventBus bus = MessageEventBus.instance();
        bus.toObservable()
            .filter(message.userId == userId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(message -> {
               //you will only received message which match id
            });
```

2- put filter inside service:

```
public class MessageEventBus {
    private static MessageEventBus INSTANCE;
    private PublishSubject<Message> bus = PublishSubject.create();

    private MessageEventBus() {};

    public static MessageEventBus instance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new MessageEventBus();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void send(Message message) {
        bus.onNext(message);
    }

    //filter here
    public Observable<Message> toFilteredObservable(int userId) {
        return bus
                .filter(message -> message.userId == userId)
                ;
    }

    public Observable<Message> toObservable() {
        return bus;
    }

    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return bus.hasObservers();
    }
}
```

and call like this inside presenter:

```
bus.toFilteredObservable(int userId)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(message -> {

});
```

PS:if you want the observable to take care of observer criteria, you should implement manually the pattern.